# Residue theorem for $ I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{\mathrm{i}\,t\,z}}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)} \, \mathrm{d}z$

Tags: integration, exponential-function, improper-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

If I use the residue theorem to evaluate the integral

$$ I(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{\mathrm{i}\,t\,z}}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)} \, \mathrm{d}z$$

with $t>0$, $\mathrm{Im}(z_1)>0$ and $\mathrm{Im}(z_2)<0$, I would have thought to get

$$ I(t)=2\,\pi\,\mathrm{i}\,\frac{e^{\,\mathrm{i}\,t\,z_1}}{z_1-z_2}$$

since only the pol in the upper half plane contributes to the integral. If I solve the integral with Mathematica 12.0 it evaluates to

$$ I(t)=2\,\pi\,\mathrm{i}\,\frac{e^{\,\mathrm{i}\,t\,z_1}-e^{\,\mathrm{i}\,t\,z_2}}{z_1-z_2}$$

even though I set the correct assumptions on $z_1$ and $z_2$ and allowed for the calculatoin of the Cauchy principal value.

Now I am wondering if I misunderstood the residue theorem or Mathematica evaluates the integral incorrectly.

Comment: $\text{Clear}[t,z,\text{z1},\text{z2}];\text{Integrate}\left[\frac{Exp[I  t z]}{(z-\text{z1}) (z-\text{z2})},\{z,-\infty ,\infty \},\text{Assumptions}\to t>0\ \&\&\ \Im(\text{z1})>0\ \&\&\  \Im(\text{z2})<0\right] $ yields
$\large \frac{2 i \pi  e^{i t \text{z1}}}{\text{z1}-\text{z2}}$ in $M_{12}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The OP's answer is indeed correct.  Why do you believe that the integral is invariant in $z_1$ and $z_2$?  Only one of them will be in the upper-half plane.

Comment: @Felix Marin: It is really interesting. If I set the option $\mathrm{PrincipalValue} \rightarrow True$ then it gives the incorrect results. If the option is false, the result is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Note that if you compute$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{itz}}{z^2+1}\,\mathrm dz,\tag1$$with $t>0$, you will get $\pi e^{-t}$. But $(1)$ is equal to$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{itz}}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}\,\mathrm dz,$$with $z_1=i$ and $z_2=-i$. Your answer will then be$$2\pi i\frac{e^{-t}}{2i},$$which is correct. But that answer provided by Mathematica 12.0 will then be$$2\pi i\frac{e^{-t}-e^t}{2i},$$which is wrong.